# My code is removing more than i want it to from my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I am trying to make a coin collection system using p5.js and when i call the destroy function it deletes the object i want it to but also every object in the array after that.

```
destroy(){
    let index = coins.findIndex(function (item){
      return item == this;
    });
    
    coins.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet that has (minimal) code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @trincot how do i  do that using p5.js?

Comment: You can include it in the snippet with a `<script src>` reference, but in essence the code you present is independent from p5, so you should really try to reproduce without p5. I mean, the functioning of `splice` does not depend on p5, but on core JavaScript. There is no reason it would behave differently because of p5.

Comment: Potentially you can extract the problem to an example that does not need p5.js? The code you present in itself seems correct to me (if you `console.log(coins)` before and after the `coins.splice` you likely see that it only removes one element), so the problem is likely somewhere else

Comment: @A_Ai did that and it shows me its calling the destroy function on all coins after the one i touch in the array. if more code is helpful i can leave a link to the p5.js page. https://editor.p5js.org/25foxm/sketches/JoTzm-E6e

Comment: The only hypothesis I have for now is that it removes the last element for you if an item is not found. It happens, because `.findIndex()` returns `-1` when item is not found and `.splice(-1, 1)` removes the last element. Perhaps you're running it in a loop or something and it keeps removing the last element like that several times.

Comment: It's likely good to try and debug the code. Either try to understand what's happening with `console.log` statements, or use a real debugger as provided by the browser tools. When you try it with the browser tools, in your case the script is loaded as `blob:https://prev...`, there you could set a breakpoint at `delete` and then step through it and inspect the variables to see what's happening

Comment: Sounds like you still need to [edit] the post to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by rewriting your findIndex to be

```js
destroy(){
    const index = coins.findIndex((item) => item === this);
    print(coins);
    coins.splice(index, 1);
    print(coins);
  }
```

The triple equal sign is strict sameness check (see more at the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)), but was not the issue you were experiencing. I also refactored the function to a 1-line arrow function, which fixed the issue.

"this" is undefined in the original function, which as @Robo Robok pointed out in his comment, means that the -1 is splicing off everything else in your list. Your second coin on the left, if you stand on it, "this" being undefined makes your findIndex function return -1, which splicing -1 removes the last coing from the array (the top-center coin). The draw function calls your collect method again, which does the same steps as before, but removing the last coin is now the second coin in the array (the one you're standing on), which is why the 1st coin (bottom center) is not removed.

I'll admit I'm not certain why "this" was undefined, my best guess is it has something to do with how js objects are created. In the pre ECMA 2015 era, class objects were created in a way like this

```js
function MyObj(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

const myObj = new MyObj(10, 50);
```

Which leads me to believe that the callback function you supplied was using the scope of its own "this" as opposed to the coin "this"